# Supervisor wont run file located in /usr/bin but I can run it if I cd to it and run it manually

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I can't get supervisor to run the laravel echo server on my Ubuntu 16.04 AWS EC2 instance but it runs fine on my Homestead Ubuntu 16.04 VM. The error I get it is can't find command '/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server. If I cd directly to `/usr/bin` and run `laravel-echo-server start` it starts up in dev mode just fine

I am running node V8.9.1

Here is what is inside my config file

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)04d
command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html/bcbAPI
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/bcbAPI/storage/logs/echoserver.log
stderr_logfile=/var/www/html/bcbAPI/storage/logs/echoserver-error.log
```

laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "http://myip.com/b3",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "aa41c60c83ffa7f7",
            "key": "70e24d91c54f9f30d1fbdb2ed3f2cce8"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
                "port": "6379",
                "host": "localhost"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {
        "wsEngine": "uws"
    },
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "myiphere/b2",
        "allowMethods": "GET,POST,PUT",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try change your command to `/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html/bcbAPI`

Comment: I'm getting this error `spawnerr: can't find command '/usr/bin/node`. `which node` shows `usr/local/bin/node` so I tried that and I'm getting these errors `2018-01-18 15:28:58,702 INFO spawned: 'laravel-workertwo_0000' with pid 6026
2018-01-18 15:28:58,762 INFO exited: laravel-workertwo_0000 (exit status 0; not expected)
2018-01-18 15:28:59,764 INFO gave up: laravel-workertwo_0000 entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly`

Comment: Change the command to `laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html/bcbAPI` if you installed laravel echo server globally

Answer (score 0):

Before everything, check the absolute paths for **NodeJS** and **laravel-echo-server**:

```
which node
which laravel-echo-server
```

After add nodejs and laravel-echo-server **PATH** into your command:

```
command=/bin/node /bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir=YOUR_ABSOLUTE_PROJECT_PATH
```

Problem solved!